# What's the most efficient way of writing a lot of data into DynamoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently migrating a system from using MongoDB to DynamoDB.
The latest challenge I am faced with is how I can speed up the import from data from MongoDB to DynamoDB.

At the moment, we have a PHP script that reads the data from MongoDB, and then BulkWrites the data 25 records at a time to the DynamoDB. Writing the data is very slow, and at current rates (even after setting write capacity to 10000), it will take 24 days to complete the transfer.

For example reading 12904 records from MongoDB take 3 seconds.
Writing those same records to DynamoDB takes 100 seconds.

How can I make this more efficient?
I'm about to look into threading so I can far more parallel write, but would it be more efficient in Node or Python rather than PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you compared runtime of the PHP script with the runtime of your DB for the queries? What is the relation?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer good point. I have a strong feeling it's the speed of the PHP script rather than the inserts being throttled.

Comment: Late, but its far more likely that the inserts are your bottleneck. 25 items per round-trip, which is most likely ~0.1s. If you're not parallelizing it, you're only going to get around 250 writes per second, no matter how high your capacity is.

Comment: @Mars you are correct, it needed to be parallelized. There were also lots of other marginal gains made to the the script which meant the import could be done in minutes.